# Does tradingview require a subscription to publish scripts publicly?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I tried publishing my scripts but tradingview does not allow me to,
does tradingview require a subscription to publish scripts publicly?

Answer (score 0):

According to TradingView

> Users of all types of accounts on TradingView can publish scripts publicly or privately.

> Basic accounts are limited to two public script publications per month. There is no limit on the number of private publications.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000590599-script-publishing-rules/